# Can't see Code on Visual Studio Team Services visualstudio.com

Tags: azure-devops

When I am adding a user to a project I get a yellow note:

> NOTE: The user xxxxxxx@outlook.com has access to limited functionality as a Stakeholder. Basic access level is required for access to version control and Agile tools.

Also the user sees a message

> As a stakeholder, you can access the backlog, task and Kanban boards, and work items. Learn more.

And the user doesn't have Code and Build tabs

I can add the same user to another project and it works fine.

I had impression that Microsoft was [offering 5 free user for Visual Studio Team Services/visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-team-services-pricing-vs.aspx).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On the Users screen (`https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_settings/users`), what's the assigned license for the specific user. The user must have a "Basic" license assigned. Even with 5 free users, it's possible to set someone to the Stakeholder category.

[image]

If your VSTS account is linked to Active Directory it is possible you may have added the user both as an Azure Active Directory (School/Work Account) as well as a Microsoft Account (formerly LiveID). These count as two separate users and each require their own license.

And finally by adding someone to the `[Project]Stakeholders` security group, you basically limit their access as well. If you want to assign more creative security permissions, you may need to setup your own security group and assign the exact permissions you want for those users to that group.

Comment: Yes this was the Users tab on the root account URL - I had old users there! gigathanks

Comment: This feature is extremely hidden! They should Add a menu for this! Thank for sharing this feature, i was struggle with this for hours!

Comment: Please note that to get this hidden menu you have to the root of your organisation, where you can see all your projects. Then click `Organisation Settings` -> `Users`  - I have update the post with correct link and also the UI has changed. But essentially if need access to code then you need to set your guest as Basic

Answer (score -1):

You should give basic access and then a contributor role to be able to access repos and pipelines. Stakeholder access is for PMO type people who need to see only the work items and tasks.

Comment: They already are part of the group direct or indirect.. still other user can not see code. Turns out you have to go to Organisation settings and set your users access level to Basic